# Show a Sothink menu on top of a Silverlight iFrame

Tags: silverlight, iframe, menu, z-index, windowless

I have a Sothink menu on a web page and below it is a Silverlight iframe application. Currently the iframe is covering some dropdown menu items.

I have tried solving this problem with z-indexing, windowless, and wmode.  I can not change the original code of the application but when I view the source of the iframe's page, I see that the developer commented out the windowless option because it interfered with another part of the program.

The only way I have tried to insert it into my page is through this code:

```
<iframe src="iframe-code-url.com" frameborder="0" style="background-color:#FFF;" scrolling="yes" width="940px" height="500px" wmode="opaque" windowless="true"></iframe>
```

I am open to any and all suggestions.  I have done a lot of research and I have not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set Windowless=true on the Silverlight host object, not the iFrame. If you can't access the host object, you cant enable Windowless mode and so you cant do what you want.

[See here for more on Windowless Silverlight Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Ideally, you should host the Silverlight XAP file in the same site as your web page.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to as well.  Unfortunately, there is no way to get the code and modify it.